# Async validation message not displaying in ngx-formly

Tags: angular, angular-forms, ngx-formly, angular2-form-validation, asyncvalidators

When trying this example from the ngx-formly library, the message that comes from the async validation is not displaying under the field as exprected

https://formly.dev/docs/examples/validation/unique-value-async-validation/

When reducing the timeout in the async validator expression, I see that the async validator  is called instantly, but the message: 'This username is already taken.' is not displayed under the field !

Here is the code from the stackblitz link:

**Template**

```html
<b>Existing usernames</b>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let u of existingUsers">{{ u }}</li>
</ul>

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <formly-form [model]="model" [fields]="fields" [options]="options" [form]="form"></formly-form>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**component class**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyFormOptions, FormlyFieldConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'formly-app-example',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model: any = {};
  options: FormlyFormOptions = {};

  existingUsers = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'];

  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'username1',
      type: 'input',
      props: {
        label: 'Username (validated using `Promise`)',
        placeholder: 'Username',
        required: true,
      },
      asyncValidators: {
        uniqueUsername: {
          expression: (control: AbstractControl) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(this.existingUsers.indexOf(control.value) === -1);
              }, 0);
            });
          },
          message: 'This username is already taken.',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'username2',
      type: 'input',
      props: {
        label: 'Username (validated using `Observable`)',
        placeholder: 'Username',
        required: true,
      },
      asyncValidators: {
        uniqueUsername: {
          expression: (control: AbstractControl) => {
            return of(this.existingUsers.indexOf(control.value) === -1);
          },
          message: 'This username is already taken.',
        },
      },
    },
  ];

  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.model));
    }
  }
}
```

**module configuration:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyModule } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import { FormlyBootstrapModule } from '@ngx-formly/bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyBootstrapModule,
    FormlyModule.forRoot({
      validationMessages: [{ name: 'required', message: 'This field is required' }],
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Stackblitz link:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3fx7j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

**Question:** is there any way to display the async validation message whenever the validation is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Step 01**
In order to display this message to the user, you'll need to subscribe to the observable and set the error message on the form control.

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
export function asyncValidator(control: FormControl): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    // simulate an asynchronous validation
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (control.value === 'test') {
        observer.next({ asyncValidation: 'Validation failed' });
      } else {
        observer.next(null);
      }
      observer.complete();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

**Step 2**
To use this validator with ngx-formly, you can define it as part of the field configuration

```
{
  key: 'test',
  type: 'input',
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Test',
  },
  validators: {
    async: asyncValidator,
  },
  validation: {
    messages: {
      asyncValidation: 'Async validation failed',
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide a working Stackblitz for this ? or fork the provided one to demo this ?

Comment: Can you update your answer with a demo, to show that it works ?, it's not working for me.